# Singleton or not. How to measure?

Tags: java, singleton

Sometimes you have to decide between using a Singleton object (a real singleton, or just a de facto singleton like an injected bean), or just using new every time. What you do really depends on the object.

If an object takes a minute to create and 10MB of memory, you do not want to create more than one if it is not necessary. But if it takes only a millisecond and 20 bytes of memory, who cares if you create 10 of them in your whole application, and the additional complications of a singleton are not worth it in my opinion.

But I would like to measure this. I found some options to see the memory usage using the Instrumentation package, but that seems to be quite difficult and cumbersome to use. So I wondered, is there some nice trick I can use, in a unit test for example, just to get some ball park figure about the memory and timing properties of an object?

To clarify: With singleton in this context I mean: An object you create only one of. Not a real singleton where you enforce that there is only one.

For example, we use resteasy to generate REST proxies. You can get the proxy with dependency injection:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public AccountRequestResource accountsServiceClient(JaxRsProxyClientBuilder builder) {
    return builder.createProxy(AccountRequestResource.class, accountsServiceBaseUrl);
}

@Autowired
AccountRequestResource accountsServiceClient
```

Or you can just construct a new one for every class where you need it:

```
AccountRequestResource accountsServiceClient = 
builder.createProxy(AccountRequestResource.class, accountsServiceBaseUrl)
```

I would like to measure these kind of problems in the general case (not just resteasy, but any type of injected object).

Comment: According to some programmers, singletons are considered an anti-pattern...

Answer (score 2):

The reason you would want to make something a singleton is not usually to save time/memory.

Suppose you have a class which maintains a **DatabaseConnection** pool. You would require to make sure you have only one of those, otherwise you will double/triple your pool and maybe overwhelm the Database.

Similarly, you might have a **Cache** class, and you would want to ensure there is only one copy of the cache so that you have consistency in your application.

The fact that you do not need to create lots of small instances of your singleton is a secondary consideration in my opinion.

In general, in a spring injected bean are not really "singletons". They are just instantiated once by the container. Nothing prevents you from doing a `new YourBean();`, thus creating two copies of the class. A **true singleton** would never let you make two copies in the same JVM.

Comment: That's why I used the term "de facto singleton". In spring beans are not real singletons, but the system will usually create only one, so they are singletons in practice.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you should make an item a singleton, is there is only ONE POSSIBLE.

This is unrelated to:
- Time it takes to create
- Memory it uses
- The fact you only use one instance in your current design.

About the last item: Suppose you makek a text editor. You decide that a document is a singleton. However, later you think it would be nice to have multiple documents ... so think twice before you make an instance a singleton. Singletons should only be singleton if you know that now AND LATER there will be only one instance of it (and even then I only use it when I need access from various points).